# Как правильно сделать встраивание div блока?

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется следующий код:

> ```
>            <div class="withdraw-history">
>                 <div class="record">
>                 @for($i=0; $i<$result; $i++)
>                     <div class="skin-picture-container">
>                         <img class="withdraw-img" src="{{asset('css/img/fabm_flight.png') }}">
>                    </div>
>                    <div class="id">
>                        <span>ID</span>
>                        {{ $id_game[$i] }}
>                    </div>
>                    <div class="sum">
>                        {{ $amount[$i] }}
>                    </div>
>                    <div class="date">
>                        {{ $date[$i] }}
>                    </div>
>                    <div class="status">
>                        <svg class="completed" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 959.000000">
>                            <g transform="translate(0.000000,959.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
>                                <path d="M12252 9569 c-35 -10 -87 -31 -116 -48 -30 -16 -1843 -1223 -4030 -2680 -2188 -1458 -3980 -2651 -3984 -2651 -4 0 -776 579 -1717 1286 -1109 834 -1733 1297 -1775 1318 -61 29 -72 31 -180 31 -109 0 -119 -2 -183 -32 -79 -38 -163 -114 -200 -181 -37 -68 -70 -197 -63 -242 20 -124 8 -105 1895 -3170 1261 -2047 1866 -3021 1899 -3057 74 -78 245 -151 329 -140 122 16 214 61 304 147 37 36 524 547 1081 1135 557 589 2361 2492 4008 4230 1647 1738 3039 3207 3093 3264 107 113 143 174 172 289 18 70 18 74 0 145 -26 106 -63 175 -125 237 -63 62 -118 92 -220 121 -83 23 -105 23 -188 -2z"></path>
>                            </g>
>                        </svg>
>                    </div>
>                @endfor
> ```

На выходе цикла for получаем такой html:

````
```<div class="withdraw-history">
       <div class="record">
          <div class="skin-picture-container">
              <img class="withdraw-img" src="http://localhost:8000/css/img/fabm_flight.png">
       </div>
           <div class="id">
               <span>ID</span>
                   87027154
           </div>
           <div class="sum">
               100
           </div>
           <div class="date">
               10.03.2022
           </div>
           <div class="status">
               <svg class="completed" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 959.000000">
                   <g transform="translate(0.000000,959.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                                <path d="M12252 9569 c-35 -10 -87 -31 -116 -48 -30 -16 -1843 -1223 -4030 -2680 -2188 -1458 -3980 -2651 -3984 -2651 -4 0 -776 579 -1717 1286 -1109 834 -1733 1297 -1775 1318 -61 29 -72 31 -180 31 -109 0 -119 -2 -183 -32 -79 -38 -163 -114 -200 -181 -37 -68 -70 -197 -63 -242 20 -124 8 -105 1895 -3170 1261 -2047 1866 -3021 1899 -3057 74 -78 245 -151 329 -140 122 16 214 61 304 147 37 36 524 547 1081 1135 557 589 2361 2492 4008 4230 1647 1738 3039 3207 3093 3264 107 113 143 174 172 289 18 70 18 74 0 145 -26 106 -63 175 -125 237 -63 62 -118 92 -220 121 -83 23 -105 23 -188 -2z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg>
           </div>
           <div class="skin-picture-container">
               <img class="withdraw-img" src="http://localhost:8000/css/img/fabm_flight.png">
           </div>
           <div class="id">
               <span>ID</span>
                   87027154
           </div>
           <div class="sum">
               1000
           </div>
           <div class="date">
               11.03.2022
           </div>
           <div class="status">
               <svg class="completed" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 959.000000">
                   <g transform="translate(0.000000,959.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                       <path d="M12252 9569 c-35 -10 -87 -31 -116 -48 -30 -16 -1843 -1223 -4030 -2680 -2188 -1458 -3980 -2651 -3984 -2651 -4 0 -776 579 -1717 1286 -1109 834 -1733 1297 -1775 1318 -61 29 -72 31 -180 31 -109 0 -119 -2 -183 -32 -79 -38 -163 -114 -200 -181 -37 -68 -70 -197 -63 -242 20 -124 8 -105 1895 -3170 1261 -2047 1866 -3021 1899 -3057 74 -78 245 -151 329 -140 122 16 214 61 304 147 37 36 524 547 1081 1135 557 589 2361 2492 4008 4230 1647 1738 3039 3207 3093 3264 107 113 143 174 172 289 18 70 18 74 0 145 -26 106 -63 175 -125 237 -63 62 -118 92 -220 121 -83 23 -105 23 -188 -2z"></path>
                   </g>
               </svg>
           </div>```
````

А нужно получить два `div блока с классом record`:

````
       <div class="record">
           <div class="skin-picture-container">
               <img class="withdraw-img" src="http://localhost:8000/css/img/fabm_flight.png">
        </div>
            <div class="id">
                <span>ID</span>
                    87027154
            </div>
            <div class="sum">
                100
            </div>
            <div class="date">
                10.03.2022
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                <svg class="completed" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 959.000000">
                    <g transform="translate(0.000000,959.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                                 <path d="M12252 9569 c-35 -10 -87 -31 -116 -48 -30 -16 -1843 -1223 -4030 -2680 -2188 -1458 -3980 -2651 -3984 -2651 -4 0 -776 579 -1717 1286 -1109 834 -1733 1297 -1775 1318 -61 29 -72 31 -180 31 -109 0 -119 -2 -183 -32 -79 -38 -163 -114 -200 -181 -37 -68 -70 -197 -63 -242 20 -124 8 -105 1895 -3170 1261 -2047 1866 -3021 1899 -3057 74 -78 245 -151 329 -140 122 16 214 61 304 147 37 36 524 547 1081 1135 557 589 2361 2492 4008 4230 1647 1738 3039 3207 3093 3264 107 113 143 174 172 289 18 70 18 74 0 145 -26 106 -63 175 -125 237 -63 62 -118 92 -220 121 -83 23 -105 23 -188 -2z"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
        <div class="record">
            <div class="skin-picture-container">
                <img class="withdraw-img" src="http://localhost:8000/css/img/fabm_flight.png">
            </div>
            <div class="id">
                <span>ID</span>
                    87027154
            </div>
            <div class="sum">
                1000
            </div>
            <div class="date">
                11.03.2022
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                <svg class="completed" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 959.000000">
                    <g transform="translate(0.000000,959.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)">
                        <path d="M12252 9569 c-35 -10 -87 -31 -116 -48 -30 -16 -1843 -1223 -4030 -2680 -2188 -1458 -3980 -2651 -3984 -2651 -4 0 -776 579 -1717 1286 -1109 834 -1733 1297 -1775 1318 -61 29 -72 31 -180 31 -109 0 -119 -2 -183 -32 -79 -38 -163 -114 -200 -181 -37 -68 -70 -197 -63 -242 20 -124 8 -105 1895 -3170 1261 -2047 1866 -3021 1899 -3057 74 -78 245 -151 329 -140 122 16 214 61 304 147 37 36 524 547 1081 1135 557 589 2361 2492 4008 4230 1647 1738 3039 3207 3093 3264 107 113 143 174 172 289 18 70 18 74 0 145 -26 106 -63 175 -125 237 -63 62 -118 92 -220 121 -83 23 -105 23 -188 -2z"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если строку `<div class="record">` перенести внутрь цикла **for**

(за строку `@for($i=0; $i<$result; $i++)`),

а также перед закрывающим `@endfor` добавить закрывающий тег `</div>` ?

Выглядит примерно так:

```
<div class="withdraw-history">
           
     @for($i=0; $i<$result; $i++)
          <div class="record">
               <div class="skin-picture-container">
                    <img class="withdraw-img" src={asset('css/img/fabm_flight.png') }}">
               </div>

                //остальной ваш код.....

          </div> <!-- закрываем class="record" -->
     @endfor
```

Comment: Thanks, anyway for the feedback)